# php move array elements by keys range

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I want the following: I have an associative array:

```
$array['a'] = 'item 1';
$array['b'] = 'item 2';
$array['c'] = 'item 3';
$array['d'] = 'item 4';
$array['e'] = 'item 5';
$array['f'] = 'item 6';
$array['g'] = 'item 7';
$array['h'] = 'item 8';
```

now I want to move array 'd','e','f' (d-f) to move after 'b' key. How to do it elegantly in php? So that I have:

```
$array['a'] = 'item 1';
$array['b'] = 'item 2';
$array['d'] = 'item 4';
$array['e'] = 'item 5';
$array['f'] = 'item 6';
$array['c'] = 'item 3';
$array['g'] = 'item 7';
$array['h'] = 'item 8';
```

Comment: You did nothing, just take rearrange code lines. all key -> value pairs are same

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [uksort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function

> uksort — Sort an array by keys using a user-defined comparison function

(From the php manual)

Comment: @JohnSmith *arranging* = user defined sorting

Answer (score -1):

Use `ksort` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: explain it better next time then